# Is FitNesse the only DSL for Selenium, or is there another DSL available?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, fitnesse

I'm looking for a DSL for Selenium (or another testing tool) that will allow a non-programmer to automate functional tests.

Comment: As a side note, I have always found things that "allow a non-programmer to <task typically done by a programmer>" end up using more resources (time, money) than they save, even if it meant hiring or contracting an actual programmer.

Answer (score 4):

A very big problem is that we are wasting a lot of time to find and learn the tool instead of just do what you want in “pure” language.

DSL is a set of subroutines that just have a specific name for your domain and do some domain-specific stuff.

You can create such procedures/functions/methods whatever on any languages of you’ve  chosen.

You can create such subroutines on any languages: Java, C#, Ruby, Perl, Python

```
// Test
// … in the middle 
var non_android_phone_vendors = “Nokia”;
varandroid_phone_vendors = “Samsung”;
goto_the_applications_home();
go_to_the_catalog();
search_for(“Android phone”);
add_first_good_to_basket();
var vendors_from_basket = get_goods_vendors_from_basket();
verify_list_does_not_contain(“Nokia”, vendors_from_basket);
verify_list_contains(“Samsung”,vendors_from_basket);
```

You do not need any tools to start creating the tests. But then, when you have a strong Automation Layer – you could add any tool you want, but any tool is not required for you to create readable tests.

The knowledge of the programming language, OOP, and best practices is the only tools you need at the beginning. Use “pure” programming language to create the DSL for your project.

Comment: "...that will allow a non-programmer to automate functional tests." Your answer misses a key point of the question.

Comment: Brian, plz see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Answer to:

> "...that will allow a non-programmer to automate functional tests."
>   Your answer misses a key point of the question. – Brian Reindel

Brian, test automation is programming the automated tests, isn’t it? 
Those keywords, like go_to_the_catalog() can be implemented by developers, and can be used by “non-programmers” later.

It is not so hard to create the tutorials how to create and run the automated tests and document all the keywords for the “non-programmers”, so those people would be able to combine and reuse the keywords.

In my opinion, thinking that the basic programming knowledge for “non-programmers”  (variables, loops, subroutines) is hard to understand – is misconception. 
Let’s say, What popular test automation tools have you seen that does not require basic programming skills? Is it SilkTest? QTP? Rational Robot? Ranorex?

Each of those tools is popular and require programming skills. Even in the Selenium IDE when some of the locators fail you have two options: do some programming and change locator or re-record all the entire test.

Using Fitnesse  or Cucumber or Robot Framework you will also need to program your own keywords. 
The same approach can be used in the pure programming language:

1. Programmers create keywords
2. Non-programmers can use the keywords, reuse and combine them in any sequence they want

Comment: I completely agree with Dmitry.  Tools like Cucumber are useless and are pushed by companies as a way for non-programmers to automate similarly to how record and playback tools were historically pushed for that purpose.  I have worked quite a bit with getting non programmers automating test cases and the approach he outlines is much simpler and just as easily adopted by non programmers as using something like cucumber.

Comment: Can't say for Cucumber, but there are some benefits to using similar tools like Robot Framework (or own custom framework). One, with the right team, you can have the less skilled QAs and even business stakeholders write the tests, while the automation "architects" create & maintain the keyword libraries used by the framework. So architects manage the actual automation hooks, while the testers and business folks maintain the test coverage. Rather than have people do both. Two, the tests are readable outside of code and IDE. Yes, you can make code readable as keywords, but it's still code.

Comment: David, if Robot Framework works for you – then I have nothing to argue. If there is really good team where automation architects helps less skilled QA to create complex keywords – that is just a good teamwork and the way to build good test automation. 
The same approach would work fine even if your less skilled QA works with pure Python. 
But any tool will not help if it was given to less skilled QA without any support from skilled Automation Engineers/Developers

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones Dan mentioned, take a look at:

- [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/), a free open-source tool with a [Selenium library](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/).
- [Twist](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist-agile-testing), an Eclipse-based commercial tool from ThoughtWorks, with Selenium support built in.

Comment: I second consideration of Robot Framework. It's the first framework I've seen that offers a great balance between developer programmability with non-programmer usability. There's still a learning curve but it's much more easier to use than say STAF (another test framework), to me anyways. And it's less restricted to some platform unlike Cucumber and RSpec.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) is an alternative.  There is also an artical on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd453038.aspx) about doing acceptance testing with IronRuby and [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) with RSpec filling the role of FitNesse I believe.

I have not used any of these though just as an aside.

Answer (score 0):

The best DSL I've found for WebDriver in Java world is [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/). Fatures I like the most

1. PageObject support
2. jQuery  content selection
3. Good integration with BDD frameworks like [Spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) (my suggestion), Cucummber etc.

   ```
   Browser.drive {
       go "http://myapp.com/login"

       assert $("h1").text() == "Please Login"

       $("form.login").with {
           username = "admin"
           password = "password"
           login().click()
       }

       assert $("h1").text() == "Admin Section"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Thucydides](http://thucydides-webtests.com/2011/09/23/hello-world/) is here. It allows groovy and is very succinct in comparison to java for writing Selenium tests.